# Serving static files from a jar file

Tags: java, maven, packaging, grizzly

I'm using [grizzly](/questions/tagged/grizzly) `StaticHttpHandler` to serve the static files from an absolute path:

```
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("/home/user/.../project/src/main/resources/static));
```

How can I package and serve the static files from the final fat jar generated by `mvn assembly:single`?

my part of my `pom.xml` file looks like

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*</include>                    
                </includes>
            </resource>             
        </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

The given configuration

```xml
<build>
  <resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
           <include>*</include>                    
        </includes>
     </resource>             
  </resources>
</build>
```

is not neccessary cause it's default.

Furthermore to get resources which are located there it's good to know that they will be packaged into the corresponding jar which can be accessed via

```java
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TheThingYoulikeToAccess.jpg"));
```

This defines a resource which is within the given jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve static files from a jar file using CLStaticHttpHandler like:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
        new CLStaticHttpHandler(new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
            new File("/home/myname/myjarfile.jar").toURI().toURL()}),  // Path to the jar file
            "my/jar/staticfiles-insider-jar/"), // the static files path inside the jar file
            "/jarstatic"); // context-path
```